# Why the rays do not continue in a straight line when passing through a prism?

Tags: optics, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, refraction

How does the lightning that is not going through a rectangle know?

a ray that passes through a rectangle, continues in a straight line

What happens to a prism made of retangles of different lengths?

that is, if we cut the prism into rectangles as thin as an atom, the ray will deviate or continue in a straight line?.

[image]

Comment: To get a slanted surface, you would need infinitely many infinitesimal tall rectangles. With finitely many rectangles, you can only approximate the shape of the prism. The change in direction of the beam of light is caused by the beam of light not hitting the boundary at right angles, so with finitely many rectangles, you'd expect light not to change direction. With infinitely many rectangles, I guess you could argue the same, but the answer loses physical meaning.

Comment: if the layers are atomize you will not have a rectangular surface, Atomscome not rectangular -;)

Comment: As long as the rectangles are quite a bit smaller than the wavelength of the light then that should refract.

Answer (score 1):

> How does the [light] that is not going through a rectangle know?

The difference is that light travels more slowly in glass than it does in air. In fact it travels at roughly 67% of *c* when travelling through glass.

But that isn't enough to explain why light bends at an air-glass interface.

Actually, like most of physics (some might even claim all of physics), ray optics is only an approximation to reality. When you look carefully at how light behaves, you can quickly find behavior that can't be explained or even modeled in ray optics (for example, diffraction phenomena like those seen in [Young's double-slit experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment)).

Luckily, while refraction can't be *explained* by ray optics, it can at least be modeled pretty accurately by ray optics in many cases. And it is modeled by [Snell's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law), usually expressed by the equation

$$\frac{\sin\theta_2}{\sin\theta_1}=\frac{n_1}{n_2}$$

which relates the index of refraction of the two materials involved to the sines of the angle of the ray relative to the normal (the direction perpendicular to the surface where the two materials meet).

If you study wave optics, you will be able to explain this behavior in terms of the velocity of the wave in the two media and the boundary conditions at the surface. But within the context of ray optics, you simply have to accept it as an observed fact.

> that is, if we cut the prism into rectangles as thin as an atom, the ray will deviate or continue in a straight line?.

Again, this question depends on the limitations of ray optics as an approximation to reality.

Once the size of your rectangles is roughly the same as the wavelength of the light involved (which is probably a few hundred times the size of an atom), ray optics will no longer be able to predict the behavior of the beam, and you'd need to work in wave optics to predict the outcome.

Once the size of the rectangles is much much smaller than the wavelength of the light (which includes your scenario where the size is the same as an atom), then ray optics can be applied again, simply treating the surface as a smooth one, and ignoring the tiny deviations in the prism's surface that are too small to strongly affect the light beam's behavior.

Comment: Hello. If the wavelength is much larger than the size of medium does that mean some energy does not enter the medium?

Comment: @FacingDownZ, yes, but ray optics isn't able to model this scenario.